# A "has_type" or "type_exists" type_trait?

Tags: c++, types, exists, sfinae, type-traits

I would like to use a type-trait class that detects if a type is defined or undefined, with the following signature:

```
template< typename T, ... >
struct has_type
{
    ...
    bool value;
}
```

Instead of `has_type`, maybe `type_exists` is a better name.

Is it possible to create such a thing?  If so, how?

**Background**: I have two implementations of a class-type, where one relies on a Standard, yet *optional* type, and I have another implementation that doesn't rely on this *optional* type.  I'd like to conditionally instantiate each of these implementations using `has_type<optional_type>` SFINAE.  ( Or rather, I'd really like to avoid configuration-tools trying to compile simple test-programs to determine if such types exist or not, then feed that information back into the build of the real code through DEFINES. )

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/19884446/2925619

Comment: Post a few more details about how you want to use this. There's bound to be a much simpler, cleaner solution. (You can check for *member* types, but not for arbitrary bare words.)

Comment: @KerrekSB  In one case, I am `reinterpret_cast`-ing object&function pointers to integral-types to enumerate pointers in a range.  `std::uintptr_t` is designed for storing object or function pointers, but not always available.  Casting to `char*` is fine for object pointers, but not for function pointers.  So, when uintptr_t is unavailable, I'll use a `union` of a `unsigned char[sizeof(T)]` with the object or function pointer.  But to switch between them, I need something like `has_type<uintptr_t>`.

Comment: As Kerrek says, you can't check for a non-member type like that. In that example, `#ifdef UINTPTR_MAX` should do the business.

Comment: @Oktalist Ah, yes, in this case that will work nicely.  For the general case however, it'd be nice to have a solution.