# How to use this is_class SFINAE?

Tags: c++, sfinae

I am trying to learn SFINAE. However, all examples I see are too complicated with negligible and non-practical achievements. The most meaningful SFINAE I have found is this one:

```
template<typename T>
class is_class {
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no [2];

    template<typename C>
    static yes& test(int C::*); // selected if C is a class type

    template<typename C>
    static no&  test(...);      // selected otherwise

public:
    static bool const value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

But, all documentations focus on writing templates without any `main` function. So, I do not know how to use them in a `main` function which does not fail when compiling.

PS. Let's forget `std::is_class` (in case of any troll commenting).

Comment: Do you want explanation of that traits (which uses SFINAE), or how to use that traits for SFINAE ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does this SFINAE C++ syntax work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884446/how-does-this-sfinae-c-syntax-work)

Comment: *"Let's forget std::is_class (in case of any troll commenting)."* - Instead of blanket "trolling" accusations, how about asking the question you are really curious about *clearly*, rather than presenting a supposedly pointless example that requires a post script?

Comment: Or maybe look at type traits

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, you are linking to a none related question. I asked something else.

Comment: So what did you try for your `main` function that is not working?

Comment: @AlbertoMiola, I just look for an answer to this question rather than implementing the program in a different way.

Comment: @DarkFalcon, I have no idea about how to use this sfinae at all.

Comment: Then why do you think you need it?

Comment: @StoryTeller, Each time I ask a question on SO, I have to fight for many things not related to the question. How about answering the question which is asked clearly. Everyday using this website gets harder.

Comment: @DarkFalcon, This is the simplest example I found on SFINAE to learn. Other examples are hard. I am going to learn SFINAE for the first time.

Comment: Everybody here will gladly do their best to answer a *clear* question. The onus is on you to make your question clear. And intentionally butting heads with everyone who tells you it's unclear is not gonna help you.

Comment: My point is that SFINAE is a tool, not an end goal. It can be used to accomplish a lot. We don't do a lot of abstract teaching here. The focus of this site is mostly on practical problem-solving. So what practical problem are you wanting to solve with SFINAE-based metaprogramming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use it that way:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<is_class<T>::value>
foo(const T&)
{
    std::cout << "is a class\n";
}

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!is_class<T>::value>
foo(const T&)
{
    std::cout << "is not a class\n";
}
```

and then in `main`:

```
int main()
{
    std::string s;
    int i = 42;

    foo(s); // a class
    foo(i); // not a class
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/544758382dd7de6c)

Regular ways to use SFINAE on functions are:

- in template parameter:

  ```
  template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<some_trait<T>::value, int> = 0>
  void foo(const T&);
  ```
- as return type:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  std::enable_if_t<some_trait<T>::value> foo(const T&);
  ```
- as parameter:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  void foo(const T&, std::enable_if_t<some_trait<T>::value, int> = 0);
  ```

You can also use SFINAE with "expression"

```
template <typename T>
auto foo(const T& t) -> decltype (bar(t)); // Only available if `bar(t)` exists.
```

Comment: Is SFINAE designed to be used with an `enable_if` or `enable_if_t`.

Comment: `std::enable_if_t` is a typedef (actually `using`) declaration for `typename std::enable_if::type`. It's just easier to write and read

Comment: using `std::enable_if`_t` uses SFINAE, but it can be done with other things. `template<typename C> yes& test(int C::*)` also use SFINAE, as `test<int>(0)` would discard this overload thanks to SFINAE (as `int int::*` is ill formed).

Comment: SFINAE discard overloads for given instantiation. You still have to have valid overload(s) with a better one.

Comment: If I try to reproduce your simple example it does not compile for me:

`template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<T>::value>
void foo(const T&)
{
    std::cout << "is a class\n";
}

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_class<T>::value>
void foo(const T&)
{
    std::cout << "is not a class\n";
}

int main()
{
  int a;
  std::string s;
  
  foo(a);
  foo(s);

  return 0;
}`

with error "error: two or more data types in declaration of ‘foo’"

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: @ad3angel1s: Demo added. your version has 2 return type, `std::enable_if_t` and .. `void`. remove extra `void`.

Comment: @Jarod42, thank you, what a silly mistake! :)

Comment: @Jarod42 could you recommend a good book for C++ generic programming? I find myself struggling with these kind of advanced concepts

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a (fairly useless) function that returns the size of a passed argument in bytes, but you want that function to only be usable with classes (for some different, strange reason). The usage of your SFINAE class:

```
template<typename T>
class is_class {
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no [2];

    template<typename C>
    static yes& test(int C::*); // selected if C is a class type

    template<typename C>
    static no&  test(...);      // selected otherwise

public:
    static bool const value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

can be:

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<is_class<T>::value>>
auto get_class_size(T t) {
    return sizeof(T);
};
```

and then, in `main()`:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> some_vec;
    int some_int;

    std::cout << get_class_size(some_vec) << '\n';
    //std::cout << get_class_size(some_int) << '\n'; // will result in
    // compilation error
}
```

Comment: Here is the problem. The SFINAE fails on the second case. I prefer that it works for both. Just in the first case it prints `the type is class` and in the other case it prints `the type is not a class`.

Comment: You should've included that in your question then. Jarod's answer answers exactly that